# Unable to Open Com Port

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi AskUbuntu community.

I want ask a question about the opening of serial ports in Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 20.04 in my MSI computer.

I want to access a hardware device (A GPS unit) via USB cable. I installed the ROS2 driver of the device and tried the below code example:

> ros2 launch sbg_driver sbg_device_launch.py

After that I got the error message:  **sbgInterfaceSerialCreate: Unable to open the com port: /dev/sbg**

To fix the error, I added myuser to dialout and tty groups but the error did not be fixed.

Can you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379179/unable-to-open-com-port/) by [mfatih](https://answers.ros.org/users/75248/mfatih/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-01**:
This is clearly a cross-post (the OP hasn't even removed the salutation) of [Unable to Open Com Port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341170) on AskUbuntu.

The cross-post there even has responses.

@mfatih: please do not cross-post, or at least not within a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Chances are your serial device is not named `/dev/sbg`

Try:

1. Unplugging your usb->serial
   converter.
2. Run `ls /dev` in a terminal
3. Plug in the usb->serial converter
4. Run `ls /dev` again.
5. Look for a newly added device (probably something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`)
6. Edit `config/sbg_device_uart_default.yaml` to use the new device instead of `/dev/sbg`

---

Originally posted by [djchopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/74140/djchopp/) with karma: 328 on 2021-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mfatih](https://answers.ros.org/users/75248/mfatih/) on 2021-06-04**:
Thanks, this method fixed my problem.